How can I highlight column for terminal in Py-script?
I want to display terminal exactly like the DOM but terminal displays "<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x4124bf0>".How can I make terminal display exactly like DOM with highlight column?
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyscript import display
import html2text
import io
html_content = '''
  <tr>
    <th>Data 1</th>
    <th>Data 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Calcutta</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Robots</td>
    <td>Jazz</td>
  </tr>
''' 
text_content = html2text.html2text(html_content) 
df = io.StringIO(text_content)
df = pd.read_csv(df, sep="|")
print(df)
def highlight_col(x):
        r = 'background-color: red'
        df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
        df1.iloc[:, 0] = r
        return df1    
display(df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None))
print(df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None))


What terminal? I don't see the code for a terminal here? So either you mean something else or this is not a complete example. Is the page related to this shared online somewhere? Sharing that would solve it not being a complete example. Plus which one of the display() or print() results in <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x4124bf0>? Include text of the example output, especially since this is incomplete provided code.

I tried the following:   https://_12.pyscriptapps.com/dataframe/latest/   .In Py-script  display() is for DOM and print() is for terminal. print()  results in <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x4124bf0> .In the code I am able to display dataframe  on terminal not sure why dataframe highlight column doesn't display on terminal.

Ohhhh. You cannot use a Pandas styler in a terminal display directly. It is for HTML handling scopes. It is really meant for only using with Jupyter, see the documentation here. I suspect though you can get something like it in terminal if you combine in using Rich and pyscript maybe, see https://github.com/khuyentran1401/rich-dataframe . Before we go to that though, do you really need it? If you want to make it look like you are displaying it in a terminal, can you just add a black box behind it using HTML instead? ...

 Or use JupyterLite's Voici mode in dark theme, see here. Oh, you are probably trying to embed this so you cannot. However, then I'm not understanding the expectation that a Pandas styler object would work in a terminal. They don't work in a true Python interpreter/console run on the command line in a terminal directly, right?

Related post: Using pandas styling on the command line. See the comments there. There's also here and Is it possible to display pandas styles in the IPython console?.

But how does buckaroo display pandas styler to terminal?

Is this buckaroo what you are talking about? I haven't dug into it very far yet but is clear upfront on that page in the 'About' and under the 'Compatibility' section that it is for Notebook settings. If that is wrong can you point to specifically where you see it working in a text based terminal?

I am not trying for the terminal styling. I am trying to get DOM functionality to terminal. https://_12.pyscriptapps.com/dataframe-copy/latest/  .Trying a way where I can have access to DOM highlighted column and replace it with the terminal color highlighter.

I think you need Jeff Glass here. I'm a Python/Jupyter person who likes Pyscript because I can display stuff in the web with just Python. I don't know how pyscript is making the so-called 'terminal' that pyscript has in Document Object Model of the page, and so I cannot tell you how to access it. I sort of wish you could describe the intended goal and context where you need this because I feel you are overcomplicating things here when you could just change the color background of the HTML and have something like a terminal but use what is possible, like styled dataframes, with display().

Both are same pyscript display () is same as IPython.display() in Jupiter notebook.Same code works in both environments.I thought terminal is same as buckaroo not sure.
